# Update a column in table A based on values in table B using a CASE statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I got a tricky question.

I would have a table `A` that is composed of two columns `A.ID` and `A.Cat1_Avail`. The `Cat1_Avail`-column is empty as of now.

I would like to update the values in `A.Cat1Avail` based on a logical question.
In particular, I have another table `B` that is composed of `B.ID` and `B.Feature`. `B.Feature` can hold the following values: `Cat1`, `Cat2` or `NULL`.

For matching ID's, I would like to insert a 1 in `A.Cat1_Avail` given the matching record in table `B` holds the value `Cat1` in `B.Feature`. In case of `Cat2`, `A.Cat1_Avail` should be 0.

In summary, I would like to update a column based on logical questions (do the ID's match? what is the content of `B.Feature`?).

I hope this makes things clear and is not too specific.

I guess this problem could be solved with several commands in sequence. But I would like to have a single command that can handle this problem.

Comment: Use triggers, to ensure data consistency.

Comment: If table `A` has two columns, what is `A.Feature`?  I don't follow the question.  This is why sample data and desired results (as *text tables* are so helpful!

Comment: my bad. I updated the question - A.Feature was in fact A.Cat1Avail.

Comment: I recommend reviewing this question .as it seems "similar" and has some very good ideas discussed (including why not to use triggers ;) )   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21110669/trigger-alternatives-for-two-tables-that-have-to-mutually-update-each-other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use merge to achieve it as following:

```
MERGE INTO TABLEA A USING (
                              SELECT
                                  ID,
                                  CASE FEATURE
                                      WHEN 'cat1'   THEN 1
                                      WHEN 'cat2'   THEN 0
                                  END AS CAT
                              FROM
                                  TABLEB
                          ) B ON ( A.ID = B.ID )
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET A.CAT1_AVAIL = B.CAT
```

Cheers!!

Comment: And this one works out nicely. Didnt know you could insert cases and joins in a MERGE-command :)

Answer (score 0):

Update statement !

```
UPDATE testa set testa.lvalue = (case when testb.lvalue = 'cat1' then 1 
                                        when testb.lvalue = 'cat2' then 0
                                        else null end)
    FROM testa join testb on (testa.id = testb.id)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

**Kindly try it**

```
Update a
set 
a.Cat1Avail = (case WHEN b.Feature = 'cat1' THEN 1
                    WHEN b.Feature ='cat2' THEN 0
                    ELSE NULL End)
from A a 
join B b
on a.ID= b.ID
```